# NumberInput mouse wheel handling disregards event filtering in capture phase

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

## Very short version:

I am a bit stuck and do not quite understand why this code does work for intercepting and preventing mouse wheel events from being interpreted by number-edit for changing the number. I would like to understand *why* intercepting the capturing and filtering the event does not work:

HTML-code:

```
<p id="p-number-1">
  <input id="number-1" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="number-input">
</p>
<p id="log">
</p>
```

JavaScript-Code:

```
function log(m) {
  const logp = document.getElementById("log")
  logp.innerHTML += "" + m + "<br>";
}

log("Logging started")

const pnum1 = document.getElementById("p-number-1")
const num1 = document.getElementById("number-1")

pnum1.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) { 
    log("captured outer");
    e.stopPropagation();
}, true);

num1.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) { 
    log("bubble inner");
}, false);

num1.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) { 
    log("capture inner");
}, true);

function log(m) {
  const logp = document.getElementById("log")
  logp.innerHTML += "" + m + "<br>";
}

log("Logging started")

const pnum1 = document.getElementById("p-number-1")
const num1 = document.getElementById("number-1")

pnum1.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) { 
    log("captured outer");
    e.stopPropagation();
}, true);

num1.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) { 
    log("bubble inner");
}, false);

num1.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) { 
    log("capture inner");
}, true);
```

Instructions: Click on the number input to focus it, then use the mouse wheel. Mouse wheel gets intercepted by the javascript code, but then still changes the number, even though I stop propagation in the capture phase on the surrounding

.

For your convenience: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljku4gha/6/

### What am I trying to achieve?

I would like to write a reusable component using the default number-input field (and sliders, actually). I do not want the user to be able to use the scroll wheel on those inputs for changing the number. Instead, the mouse wheel should trigger events on some (unknown!) surrounding div (most likely), for scrolling purposes. So I would like to stop the number-edit (and slider) from handling the mouse wheel events in some way.

## Longer version: My analysis/hypotheses

I cannot *quite* explain it, but have two hypotheses of what is going on.

My first and I think most likely idea is that this is an artifact of how browsers handle user-events (keyword "user agent", I think). However, it would be very nice to find actual details about this somewhere, if someone has pointers where to read up on how browsers handle user events, that would be very welcome. Until then, here what I understand about event handling in browsers:

- User scrolls mouse wheel
- JavaScript gets its turn in handling the event

  - JavaScript does its capture/bubble stuff
  - EventHandlers are allowed to mark the even as handled (preventDefault())
- Outside of JavaScript: If event-handlers in JavaScript did not call preventDefault() the "user agent" gets its turn to handle the event. Since there is no fine grained control over this, this step can only be stopped entirely or go through. Since the "default handling" for the number edit is changing the number-value, the number is changed and no scroll event is emitted.

Result: `*sad me*`

However, I think this theory makes the most sense but maybe it is entirely wrong?!

### Alternative boring explanation: I listen for the wrong event?

Maybe I am missing something and the wheel-event gets translated to some other event that I can preventDefault() on? I could not find anything about that, but it would make perfect sense to me... maybe? It is not a "scroll" even, I can tell that much.

---

I would primarily like to get some pointers that help me understand why what I am doing does not work... and a solution would also be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent default behavior of the number input.

We have 2 improvements here:

- prevent wheel when the input is focused only (when the wheel changes the value). That way when the input isn't focused the wheel behaves as usual
- when the input is focused prevent the default AND blur the input so the next wheel event the scrolling would work again (you should decide whether you need this tweak).

You cannot fix that with the capturing because

**When you capture the default behavior happens before the event bubbles up to the input unfortunately**

So `stopPropagation()` doesn't help in the capturing phase.

```js
const p = document.getElementById("p-number-1")
const num1 = document.getElementById("number-1")



num1.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) { 
    console.log("input wheel");
    if(e.target.matches(':focus')){
      console.log("input wheel prevented");
      e.preventDefault();
      e.target.blur();
    }
}, false);
```

```css
p{
  height:1000px;
}
input{
  pointer-events: none1;
}
```

```html
<p id="p-number-1">
  <input id="number-1" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="number-input">
</p>
<p id="log">
</p>
```

Comment: Follow-up question here for: "to prevent default behavior of the number input."

This "default-behavior" is executed far away from my JavaScript code somewhere in the bowels of the browser right? After stopPropagation(), my possibilities of interacting with the scroll event stop entirely.

Comment: @PKCakeout when you capture the default behavior happens before the event bubbles up to the input unfortunately.

Comment: @PKCakeout added some tweak to resume scrolling with the wheel when the input is focused